# Data render before server call in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

All the times cannot read the property of undefined (reading 'image')

also i can see api does not call if i remove everything from return it does work well it does call useEffect but after return it does not call what is causing issue please guide

```
    const { id } = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    let user = useSelector(store => store.userById.data)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("******UseEffect***");
        dispatch(action.userById(id))
    }, [id]);

 return (
        <section id="rentalDetails">
         <img src={user.image} alt={user.title} />
       </section>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be defensive and do not render the user related data if there is no `user` yet.

```
 return (
        <section id="rentalDetails">
         {user && <img src={user.image} alt={user.title} />}
       </section>
 )
```

Or provide a default object to the `user` until the api returns.

```
const user = useSelector(store => store.userById.data || {})
```